# Calculate number of zeros in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string as follow  `51200000000000000000000000000000`

This string is not fixed. It will be appended depends on the number of boards. If there are two boards, the string will be as follow `5120000000000000000000000000000052200000000000000000000000000000`

I would like to know how to calculate the number of zeros in the string.

I'm using the following code but it is not flexible if there are more than two boards.

```
string str = "51200000000000000000000000000000";
string zeros = "00000000000000000000000000000";
if (str.Contains(zeros))
{
     Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

Comment: Convert string to char array and loop

Comment: 1. Iterate over characters of a string with simple `for` 2. Count zeroes

Comment: @Prashant `String` has indexer for that already.

Comment: do you mean you want to count the max number of "0" of a sub-string inside a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to do this, which will give you the number of zeros([Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RchVzU)).

```
char matchChar='0';
string strInput = "51200000000000000000000000000000";
int zeroCount = strInput.Count(x => x == matchChar); // will be 29
```

You can do the same by iterating through each characters and check whether it is the required character(say `0`) then take its count.

Comment: A note to community: even though this answer is technically more concise, the thing is that the other encourages the algorithmic thinking (that is "better" from the perspective that it's a skill to solve arbitrary tasks).

Comment: A note to community: while I do agree with @zerkms, I feel that taking this point to its logical extreme would suggest that writing this code in assembler would be even better still to encourage algorithmic thinking. ;-)

Comment: @Enigmativity OP cannot write a loop, and the checked answer is LINQ. I see a huge gap between the answer and demands in *understanding* it. I agree that pragmatism should be preferred over extremes, but when there are no basic skills gained by the OP yet it's a bit early to teach them LINQ (my opinion).

Comment: @zerkms - I do agree with you.

Comment: @zerkms I think there is a need for me to explain my situation. I've written for loop and Linq before. The reason I chose this answer is because I'm pushed to code for a product that'll be in the market in a few months time but I'm new in this and have limited knowledge on c#. I now know both methods but I prefer to put Linq in my code to look more professional.

Answer (score 8):

Use a simple `foreach` loop to traverse the string and count:

```
int CountZeroes(string str)
{
    // TODO: error checking, etc.
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var character in str)
    {
        if (character == '0') count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a little advanced (or so) technique would be to convert the `string` to `char array` then to `list of chars` then using `LINQ`

```
        string str = "51200000000000000000000000000000";

        List<char> nums = str.ToCharArray().ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(nums.Where(x => x.Equals('0')).Select(x => x.ToString()).Count());
```

i just placed this here in case you want to learn not just a single approach :)

Comment: You can skip `.Select(x => x.ToString())` and apply `.Count()` directly after where, `nums`  is also not needed since you can apply `where` to `str`

Comment: indeed, although in future use of LINQ syntax, one will definitely be using select. :D also you can use List<int> if you are iterating through a numeric only string :)

Answer (score 3):

> using **System.Linq**

```
int count0s = str.Count(z => z == '0');
```

will return how many 0's in your **`str`** string

Answer (score 0):

It can also do with a **[`for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)** loop and **[`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

**Code**

```
string str = "51200000000000000000000000000000";
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str.Substring(i, 1) == "0")
    n += 1;
}
Console.WriteLine("Count : " + n.ToString());
```

**[`Working fiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ayRAD)**

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
    string st;
        st = textBox1.Text;
        int countch = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
            if (st[i]=='0') countch++;           
        MessageBox.Show(countch.ToString());
```